# How to just execute a command in robotlegs without making him listening for an event?

Tags: robotlegs

How to just execute a command in robotlegs without making him listening for an event?

Another way, but not this one:
"It is not necessary, and should never be done, to call the execute() method directly. This is the framework implementation’s job."

http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/faqs/reference-mvcs-implementation/how-are-commands-triggered-in-mvcs-implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, please read the Robotlegs documentation and ASDocs ( http://api.robotlegs.org/ ). If you had, you would have seen this:

http://api.robotlegs.org/org/robotlegs/core/ICommandMap.html#execute%28%29

Comment: But I read somewhere that calling dirrectly execute() on a command is bad design.. There are no other ways?

Comment: I did not say you should call execute on the command. You can execute commands through the CommandMap. Did you even follow the link I posted?

Comment: Yes I read.. So I have to use the execute(Command) on the command map, right?

Comment: Yes, that will make sure that dependencies are injected into the Command instance before it is executed.

Comment: StackOverflow is a perfectly fine place to ask RL questions. CommandMap#execute should do it. Can you explain why you want to do this?